# How to open an excel file and then click a button by python?

Tags: python, excel

When I open and excel file, the excel show me a message.

"Do you want to open this excel file anyway?"   Yes, No, Cancel

I want to open it by **python** and automatically click **Yes** by python too. I don't know what to do. I am totally beginner in python. I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Solution here... https://appuals.com/file-format-and-extension-dont-match/

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to open your file using python, and what do you mean open ?
This works for me  :

```
pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
```

more on it here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: my problem is after the program open the excel file. it open a question that this excel file is unsafe... do you want to open it anyway? YES No Cancel I don't know what to do with this question I want to click the button yes. after that I want to change the column which I know what to do with it. but I don't know what to do with this question?!